# Why can't I drag files from File Explorer in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, file-browser

I am trying to drag files from a view with the File Explorer into the Sequencer view of the Video Sequence Editor.
However, my mouse drag only selects multiple files instead of dragging. I've tried left click, middle click, right click, double click, shift click, ctrl click, alt click, <~Goddamn-I-really-need-this-feature~> click... To no avail :(. 
I'm using the latest Blender as of today, on Linux Mint 17.2 (Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty equivalent).

Moreover, I believe there should be a button, at least, for "import selection into VSE" or "add the selected object as a strip". I don't have anything like that on the 'menu' bar of file browser view.

Lastly, I can drag and drop files from Nemo, the default file manager on my system.

Sorry for not asking something more interesting :(. I'm getting there...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must left-click and drag the ICON in the File Browser. Clicking anywhere else only selects the asset. You should then be able to drag it into the timeline. Bear in mind that you can only add one file at a time this way.

Comment: and the prize for the best-hidden 'feature' goes to ... :D. Thank you! I had the list view selected so in no way I would've figured to click on the icon

Comment: List view has little icons as well ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There is a Blender add-on called [Easy-Logging](http://easy-logging.net/).  It adds an import button in the Sequencer header that "imports" selected file from file browser and brings it into the timeline.  So far it can only do one file at a time, even if multiple files are selected.
[image]